# Rails 5: How to query Activerecord models in a three-level nested hierarchy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I am building a two-sided market web app where users can have many 'offers' for sale. Each 'offer' can be purchased by another user, the buyer. 'Purchases' can then be rated by the buyer (0 to 5 points/stars).

**My models:**

```
User:
has_many :offers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy

Offer:
has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user

Purchase:
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :offer
```

Image representation:
[Image representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4v3C.png)

**The problem:**

I need to get a user from the database (a 'seller'), including all the purchases where he/she is the seller of the associated offer, and the purchase rating is not null.

**My attempt:**

```
    @user = User.includes(offers: :purchases).
  where(offers: { user_id: params[:seller_id] }).
  where(id: params[:seller_id]).first
```

**The result:**

I am getting purchases where he/she is the buyer. Rather, I need purchases of any offer where he/she is the seller, and the purchase rating is not null.

I am not querying the rating yet because I don't know how to include this in the query.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, the `Purchase#user_id` is in fact the _user's id who purchased_ and `Offer#user_id` is the _user'is id who is selling/has sold_, right?

Comment: If my previous comment is true, then this should work: `User.includes(offers: :purchases).where(offers: { user_id: seller_id }).where('purchases.rating IS NOT NULL')`. This means it will fetch any `User` having one or more `Offer` where he is the _seller_ AND this offer having one or more `Purchase` where the rating is not null.

Comment: Thanks, your first comment is true. Now I am doing this:  `@user = User.includes(offers: :purchases).
      where(offers: { user_id: seller_id }).
      where('purchases.rating IS NOT NULL').first` `@user` gets the user data but the `@user.purchases` collection is empty.

Comment: this is because the association between `User` and `Purchase` is in fact the _purchaser_, not the _seller_ relation, which lives in `Offer#user_id`. If you do `@user.offers.first.purchases` you will (probably) see the Purchases made with this User as a seller. You can add `has_many :as_seller_purchases, class_name: 'Purchase', through: :offers, source: :purchases` in your User model to shortcut this.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to rename your column with better names, like `Offer#user_id` could become `Offer#seller_id` and `Purchase#buyer_id`, both being foreign keys to a User record (you can config this with ActiveRecord like this, for example in Purchase model: `belongs_to :buyer_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :buyer_id`)

Comment: Thanks. I added the `has_many :as_seller_purchases` code to the User model. If now I do `@user = User.includes(:as_seller_purchases).where(offers: { user_id: seller_id }).where.not(purchases: { rating: nil }).first` it works nicely for users who have 'as_seller_purchases'. However, for uses who don't, the query returns totally empty and I can't even use `@user.name`. I think the query needs to act as a LEFT join. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you want to "alias" the `belongs_to` associations so that its clear what the association actually is:

```
class User
  has_many :offers, 
    dependent: :destroy,
    foreign_key: :seller_id # where to find user on the offers table
  has_many :purchases,
    dependent: :destroy,
    foreign_key: :buyer_id # where to find user on the purchases table
end

class Offer
  has_many :purchases
  # @todo write migration to change the column name from
  # user_id to seller_id
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end

class Purchase
  belongs_to :offer
  # @todo write migration to change the column name from
  # user_id to buyer_id
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
end
```

You can then start adding indirect associations without getting confused out of your wits:

```
class User
  has_many :offers, 
    dependent: :destroy,
    foreign_key: :seller_id // where to find user on the offers table
  has_many :purchases,
    dependent: :destroy,
    foreign_key: :buyer_id // where to find user on the offers table
  has_many :sales,
    through: :offers,
    source: :purchases
end

class Offer
  has_many :purchases
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end

class Purchase
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
  has_one :seller, through: :offer # goes through the "offer" association above
end
```

The key here is:

```
has_many :sales,
  through: :offers,
  source: :purchases
```

Which lets you traverse from a user to purchases where the user is the seller.

And:

```
has_one :seller, through: :offer
```

Which lets you go from a purchase to the seller.

```
# given @user
Purchase.where(seller: @user).where.not(rating: nil)
@user.sales.where.not(rating: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this in the coming days and (hopefully) will mark your response as the accepted answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `has_one :seller, through: :offer` be `has_one :seller, through: :offers` instead?

Comment: No - you want to go through the `belongs_to :offer` association on `Purchase` (which was omitted from the answer) so it must be singular. When you use the `through:` option it has to match the name of the association which you are joining through - not the table or class.